# Coins don't show up in game in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, game-design

I have a 2D game I'm making with Unity, and I want the player to be able to collect coins that I place all over the game. I used the coin prefab with a 2D circle collider and an animation to make it spin. The problem is that only the first coin I put into the scene shows up in the game, and when I collect that one coin, the counter shows that all the others have been collected as well. Here's the script I attached to the player for the coins:

```
private uint tokens = 0;

void OnGUI(){
    GUILayout.Label ("Tokens= " + tokens);
}

void CollectToken(Collider2D tokenCollider){
    tokens++;
    Destroy (tokenCollider.gameObject);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag ("token")) {
        CollectToken(col);  
    }
}
```

This is my current setup for the object properties:

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you check that you're not moving the position of every coin to one position?

Comment: I have them in different positions in the scene, and when the game loads it looks like they either disappear or they all move to the position of the first coin

Comment: Yes, did you check if the last thing isn't exactly what happens, and if it does debug why that is happening? Cause it's not in any of the code presented here.

Comment: It turns out it's the latter, all the prefabs are moving to one position. I've added a screen shot of the inspector, the prefab's position is set at 0, but it changes to this when I play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a bool for isCollected; so if(isCollected) token++

you want the coin to be inside a empty gameobject so when you go to animate it you are animating the child so it doesn't move all the coins to the position of where you created the first.

Comment: I tried that, but the coins are still moving to 0.25, -1.44

Comment: make sure to animate the child and not the position of the parent and your coin will animate correctly

Comment: example would be Parent named Coin and child named ItemCoin if you animate the ItemCoin your good. just make sure the Animation does not show Coin : Position

Comment: glad to hear :)